# puzzle in datetime parse without year

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I want to parse some String into Date, and format the Date into String in another style. When parsing some datetime String without year, I found the following puzzles. I have two different input string, but the outputs are same. It is really confused. Any suggestion how to fix this? Thanks.

```
System.out.println(parseAndFormat("MAR 22 12:10:23",
                "MMM dd hh:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd a HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"));
//Actual  : 1970-03-22 AM 00:10:23.000 +0800
//Expected: 1970-03-22 PM 12:10:23.000 +0800
System.out.println(parseAndFormat("MAR 22 00:10:23",
                "MMM dd hh:mm:ss", "yyyy-MM-dd a HH:mm:ss.SSS Z")); 
//Actual:   1970-03-22 AM 00:10:23.000 +0800
//Expected: 1970-03-22 AM 00:10:23.000 +0800
private static String parseAndFormat(String input, String parse,
        String format) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(parse, Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = parser.parse(input);
    String result = formater.format(date);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're always providing `hh` as your input format for hours, despite the fact that it appears you're providing values with a 24-hour clock. Use `HH` instead of `hh`. The fact that you don't have a value for the year is irrelevant to that.

Note that in your *output* format you're mixing a 24-hour format (`HH`) with an am/pm designator (`a`) which is *also* odd. Why would you want to show "1970-03-22 PM 16:10:23.000 +0800" for example? That's a very odd format.

See the docs for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details about what the various format specifiers mean.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it works. I forgot how to use 'hh' and 'HH'. It is really irrelevant to the year field.